# A word for 'independent episodes'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, technical, literary-techniques

When we have a series of episodes where every single episode depends on and develops from the previous, we may call that a sequel, or maybe a continuum.

Now let us say that we have a collection of fables, episodes or anecdotes that have the same characters, the same milieu, and the same themes; yet, this time, the episodes are NOT interdependent. They don't depend on each other in that you can watch/read 'any' one of them be it (in terms of order) from a beginning, medial, or final season, without having to watch/read the previous to understand, appreciate, and enjoy it (the one you're watching/reading). What do we call the 'episode' in this case?

Examples: a sitcom comedy show, or a show like *Dr Who*. Or, in literature, the novels of *Sherlock Holmes*.

Is there a specific term to describe the 'independent episodes' of these works?

Comment: The collection may be called an *anthology*, which implies no particular connection or relationship between the stories.

Answer (score 5):

These are **stand alone episodes**, as they "stand alone" from the main story arc.

[TV Tropes goes into detail](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StandAloneEpisode), and provides multiple examples:

> An episode that can stand alone on its own with a self-contained story that does not need prior viewing of any other episode to understand. It's usually an episode that breaks from the current arc to focus on a one-shot subplot or character; for example, if the arc is about stopping The End of the World as We Know It, a Stand Alone Episode can be about dealing with a Sealed Evil in a Can that's released at the beginning of the episode and resealed by the end of the episode, never to be mentioned again.
>
> A Stand Alone Episode can also be a Beach Episode, Breather Episode, or A Day in the Limelight, but not always; the only prerequisite of one is not to follow a script that goes on for more than one episode. When such an episode happens to be a Season Finale, it is a Dénouement Episode.
>
> Many shows can be considered a long run of Stand Alone Episodes. Comedy series usually consist entirely of Stand-Alones because each episode usually focuses on a different gag or zany schemes. Likewise, Adventure Towns series generally consist of Stand Alone Episodes.
>
> In arc-heavy series, a good Stand Alone Episode can be the hook a die-hard fan of the show can use to pull others in, due to its self-contained nature. Likewise, even fans of the arcs will often cite a Stand-Alone as their favorite episode; an arc episode is difficult to separate and appreciate outside of the arc which contains it, but a Stand Alone Episode can be fully appreciated of itself.
>   Sometimes, though, writers will want to revisit the plot of a Stand Alone Episode and create a later episode that expands on the earlier story; this is a Sequel Episode.
>
> By their very nature, the pilot episode for a show is usually a Stand Alone Episode.
>   Compare Filler, although the label is usually only used when a stand-alone episode isn't really good enough to stand at all.

Answer (score 1):

The proper word for the same is perhaps “Episodic”

OED

a. Of or pertaining to, or of the nature of, an episode; incidental, occasional.

> 1856   D. Masson Ess. Biogr. & Crit. 257   Such incidents as these, episodic as they were to the two great topics of Wilkes and the Constitution and the growing disaffection of the American colonies.

> 1879   ‘G. Eliot’ Theophrastus Such vi. 123   His episodic show of regard.

Comment: Hello B K tanna, your answer would benefit from a linked referrence to support your claim. Please enjoy the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Welcome to EL&U. (From review).

Answer (score 0):

They are just "episodes".  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/episode

If the shows follow on from each other you would probably call them "instalments" rather than episodes. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/instalment